# How to find the URLs that match with a certain pattern?

Tags: python, regex, url

I have a list of URLs that contains different types of URLs. A sample is given below:

```
url_list = [

 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/cond05-03-00/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC11/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2401/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/cond04-00-01/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/R11609/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC21/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/2011528/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/dtlrvwlst/B432614271/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0205/A020502/2008632/dtlrvwlst/B106889387/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2343/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2202/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0205/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2208/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/unagi/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2361/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0201/A020101/2005741/dtlrvwlst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0201/A020101/2010629/dtlrvwlst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2443/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/CC06/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2011530/',
]
```

From here I want to separate the URLs that have the following pattern:

```
'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/'
```

Here, `https://tabelog.com/aomori/` part is always common. And after this part, there will be always three `/` separated values (`A0202/A020201/2008713/`). In the `A0202` and `A020201` parts, it always starts with `A` but the number of digits are not the same.

So, my output should be something like below if I separate the desired URLs from the `url_list`

```
final_url_list = [
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/2011528/,
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2011530/',
]
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can separate these URLs using Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp to achieve this functionality. As for example the following pattern:

```
'https:\/\/tabelog\.com\/aomori\/A\d+\/A\d+\/\d+\/'
```

It will match all the lines ending with /' meaning it will ignore these URLs that continue.

You can debug it here:
https://regex101.com/r/ZHk534/1

And also you can generate a python example code here:
https://regex101.com/r/ZHk534/1/codegen?language=python

Comment: You will have to change the regexp to match a final line ($) cause in your example you are not having the final ' char in your urls, cause it is part of the python string definition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (I get three results filtered from your original list)...

```
import re

url_list = [

 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/cond05-03-00/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC11/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2401/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/cond04-00-01/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/R11609/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC21/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/2011528/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/dtlrvwlst/B432614271/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0205/A020502/2008632/dtlrvwlst/B106889387/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2343/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2202/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0205/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2208/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/unagi/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2361/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0201/A020101/2005741/dtlrvwlst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0201/A020101/2010629/dtlrvwlst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2443/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/CC06/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2011530/',
]

pattern = re.compile("https://tabelog\.com/aomori/A\d+/A\d+/\d+/$")
filtered_list = list(filter(pattern.match, url_list))

print(filtered_list)
```

Output:

```
['https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/2011528/', 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/', 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2011530/']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Nurio's regex:

```
import re

url_list = [

 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/cond05-03-00/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC11/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2401/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/cond04-00-01/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/R11609/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/MC21/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/2011528/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/dtlrvwlst/B432614271/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0205/A020502/2008632/dtlrvwlst/B106889387/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2343/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2202/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0205/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2208/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/unagi/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2361/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0201/A020101/2005741/dtlrvwlst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0201/A020101/2010629/dtlrvwlst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/C2443/rstLst/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/rstLst/CC06/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2011530/',
]

r = re.compile('https:\/\/tabelog\.com\/aomori\/A\d+\/A\d+\/\d+\/')
newlist = list(filter(r.match, url_list))
print (newlist)
```

Sample output:

```
['https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/2011528/', 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/dtlrvwlst/B432614271/', 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0205/A020502/2008632/dtlrvwlst/B106889387/', 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0201/A020101/2005741/dtlrvwlst/', 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0201/A020101/2010629/dtlrvwlst/', 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/', 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2011530/']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re`:

```py
import re

final_url_list = []

for url in url_list:
    m = re.findall('(.*A\d+/A\d+/\d+/$)', url)
    if len(m) > 0:
        final_url_list.append(m[0])
```

Yields a `final_url_list` of

```
['https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0203/A020301/2011528/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2008713/',
 'https://tabelog.com/aomori/A0202/A020201/2011530/']
```

I find https://pythex.org/ to be very helpful when crafting regular expressions.

Comment: Just missing a closing bracket from `final_url_list.append(m[0)`